# screen displays well on bios boot, but displays grey & black lines on OS boot

Tags: boot, display

My  laptop's screen suddenly started displaying grey & black lines after  OS selection. BIOS & grub display just fine but after selecting the OS, it goes dark then displays grey lines.  I've tried reinstalling the display driver but still it doesn't change anything. I also dont think that it is a cable issue since Grub displays just fine. what could be the issue guys.

Acer-aspire v5 131